# can i change html content using innerhtml in javascript without using a function?

Tags: javascript, html

The most basic example, where say I got a variable called name. What I want to do is to put the value of my tag paragraph to the name variable.

That is, I want the value of name change in html as soon as it is changed in JavaScript.

Btw, I created a refresh name method, which works perfectly, but I need a better alternative.

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <script>
            var droid = new Android();
            var name = "Player";
            function getName() {
                name = prompt("Enter Name");
            }
            function putName() {
                var elm = document.getElementById("ntag");
                elm.innerHTML = name;
            }
        </script>
        <p id="ntag"></p>
        <input type="button" onclick="putName();" value="Refresh Name"/>
        <input type="button" onclick="getName();" value="Change Name"/>
        <br>
        <input type="button" onclick="droid.dismiss();" value="Exit"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Question is not clear

Comment: If you mean that you want a change to a JS variable to automatically change an html element the answer is no - you'd have to add extra code to do that. But you _could_ have extra code that makes `name` an object with set and get methods that do automatically update an html element.

Comment: `<input type="text" id="ntag">` isn't an alternative?

Comment: What stops you from doing that just after the prompt? `name = prompt("Enter Name"); document.getElementById("ntag").innerHTML = name;`. So effectively, you will be doing that without needing the function `putName`.

Comment: I was asking if i could change content in my html without using a function

Comment: Yes, but why would you want to?

Comment: @rhumborl : thats quite sarcastic... What i want is to di more with the user pressing lesser buttons.

Comment: @abhitalks : well, thats basically the most sensible piece of text in those comments... I would settle for that    put it as answer so that i can +1 it

Comment: @abhitalks upload your comment as answer

Comment: @abhitalks Upload comment as answer please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand from you question, you want to minimize the number of buttons and event-handlers.

You are currently using two buttons to prompt for input and change the content. You can get rid of your `putName` function and the associated button for that and change the content within the first one itself.

You should ideally use `innerText` instead of `innerHTML` in this case.

You code will somewhat look like this snippet:

***Snippet***:

```js
function getName() {
  name = prompt("Enter Name");
  document.getElementById("ntag").innerText = name;
}
```

```html
<p id="ntag"></p>
<input type="button" onclick="getName();" value="Change Name"/>
```